# Separating HP and Attack variable from the Character class? in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers

I want to separate the hp and attack variables from the character class because there are too many of them and they require different functions separately that dedicates to the hp and attack purpose.

For example,

```
class Player
{private:
    int currentattack; 
    int maximumattack; 
    int buffedattack;
    int maximumhealth;
    int currenthealth;
    int buffedhealth;
   ....
 }
```

into

```
class Player
{private:
    Health health;
    Attack attack;
   ....
 }
```

and each Health class and Attack class with above variables. However, I don't know how to implement it so that for every smart pointers created by the Player class can obtain different Health and Attack class objects in it to save separate values for different players. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're trying to do. And you should describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is. Each new instance of `Player` will have its own default constructed instances of `Health` and `Attack`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have e.g.

```
struct Health
{
    int maximumhealth;
    int currenthealth;
    int buffedhealth;
};

class Player
{
    // ...
private:
    Health health;
};
```

Then for every `Player` instance you create (no matter how you create the instance), there will also be an `Health` instance created for it, unique and distinct for that `Player` instance.

It works just the same as for any other member variable using the simple built-in types like for example `int`.